# TextFields and text areas become unresponsive after performing validation in the textfield

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am creating a view controller in which `UITextField` are getting created dynamically.

```
self.ansText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
                self.ansText.tag = 1;
                self.ansText.delegate = self;

                [_ansText createAnsTextwithParentFrame:QuestionView.frame withUpperFrame:questSeq2Frame];

                [QuestionView addSubview:_ansText];
```

Here when I do a validation on the `UITextField`, text fields even in other view controllers become unresponsive.Here it is reaching `UITextField` ShouldBeginEditing method.I have gone through a number of similar question in stack overflow.And I saw a solution like setting the delegate not to self. But Could anyone please help me on this..Could you please elaborate on this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What you have written in shouldBeginEditing method, return YES or NO?

Comment: @Gati:   It returns YES only

Answer (score 0):

@iOSManiac, delegate can be the UITextField, it's just 
`self.ansText.delegate = ansText;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more detailed answer, your And Text must be inherited from UITextField and it must implement UITextFieldDelegate

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end


@interface  AnsText : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation AnsText 

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    return YES;
}

@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AnsText *ansText = [[AnsText alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    ansText.tag = 1;
    ansText.delegate = ansText;
    [self.view addSubview:ansText];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```